# Display any website source code for copy/paste

Tags: php, html, copy-paste

I have a website displaying data from MySQL in a php file (/something.php).... i want to copy the source code of that page as HTML so i can use it in a textfield box so users can copy paste that code...

It's almost like an HTML generator using info from mySQL, so users can custimize each HTML code.

I have everything covered... except the display HTML thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo htmlspecialchars(eval(file_get_contents('path/to/your/file')));
```

Eval is generally frowned upon however but this is a quick and easy solution.

Comment: now display this error

<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(FILE) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the HTML into HTML entities. For instance, convert `<` into `&lt;`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a php function [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) you should look into.

For rendering check either `eval` (quick & dirty) or `ob_start` and friends (the more complex way to do it, though safer and generally supported by more hosters).

Comment: i'm using it... 


<? echo . htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents(__FILE__)) .; ?>

but it's displaying the original php file... not the result of the query as html

Comment: OK, you might want to make clear in the question that you want to **render** the php and then display the *resulting* html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually *request* the page from the web server, not simply read its contents in order for the PHP to execute and produce the result. That is, if I understand correctly that PHP (the file you were simply *reading*) is querying the database to actually fetch the desired HTML to display.

So, something like (if permitted) `file_get_contents("http://url_of_php_file_you_were_simply_reading_not_requesting");` , then of course run that through `htmlspecialchars();`

Better to just use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to stay portable when requesting the page.